# Configuring Jenkins to Utilize Docker on Host Agent Server with Workspace Ownership

Tags: docker, jenkins

We are currently utilizing a Jenkins instance with the Docker Cloud plugin, which employs the label "foo" to initiate a Docker container using Docker in Docker (DnD). This setup allows for working within the container to build using Docker and maintain a clean environment. While the workspace is removed on every job, the performance is a concern due to a substantial build time caused by the inability to reuse any Docker cache, resulting in the need to download all intermediate images for every build.

Alternatively, when configuring the environment to utilize a static node with Docker without the cloud plugin, Jenkins encounters difficulty in cleaning up the workspace as it is entirely owned by root after a previous run when building some images.

While Docker in Docker (DnD) currently serves as our solution, we are seeking to enhance performance without resorting to using Docker inside a container.

The optimal solution involves configuring Jenkins to automatically remove the workspace after each build and to directly utilize Docker on the host server, rather than inside a container, while also ensuring that the Jenkins user always owns the workspace. However, I am currently unable to find a suitable configuration solution. Do you have any suggestions?